# Change interruption behavior of fulfilled AWS spot request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Before knowing exactly how AWS spot instances work I configured a spot request with the interruption behavior set to terminate. As I understand it my running instance state will be deleted on termination. So if I don't have an image backup I will not be able to start the server again in it's last state.

Since the spot request is fulfilled and the instance running, is it possible to change the interruption behavior to stop when I am outbid? I cant seem to find the option to change the interruption behavior.

Answer (score 2):

For setting the interruption behavior to stop, we need to take care of some requirements:

- For a Spot Instance request, the type must be persistent, not
  one-time. You cannot specify a launch group in the Spot Instance
  request.
- For a Spot Fleet request, the type must be maintain, not request.
- The root volume must be an EBS volume, not an instance store volume.

by following the above requirements, we can change the interruption behavior from terminate to stop.

Please refer the following url for reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html

Comment: My Spot Instance request is currently one-time and not persistent. How do I change it without terminating the running instance?

Comment: Another requirement is that hibernate only works for certain instance types.  When I tried, the following error showed up:  instanceInterruptionBehavior 'hibernate' is not supported for instance types g4dn.xlarge, d3en.xlarge, c5a.2xlarge, g4dn.2xlarge, g4dn.4xlarge, g4dn.8xlarge, g4dn.16xlarge, g4dn.12xlarge, g4dn.metal

Answer (score 1):

According to boto3 [Spot instance creation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.request_spot_instances) documentation, you may also instruct the instance to `stop` or `hibernate` if you set the instance type to `persistent`. The default behaviour is `terminate`. This features is  [added in November 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-ec2-spot-lets-you-pause-and-resume-your-workloads/).

```
response = client.request_spot_fleet(
   SpotFleetRequestConfig={
     .....
     Type='one-time'|'persistent',
     'InstanceInterruptionBehavior': 'hibernate'|'stop'|'terminate'
    }
```

Use them sparingly as each behaviour has some pros and cons, e.g. you must take care of process network connection interruption if yo use hibernate. For `stop`, you may want to store data into another mounted EBS.

Comment: Can I change the instance type from one time to persistent without terminating the spot instance?

Comment: @Rynardt  Well, you didn't see the option inside AWS Console, it means it is not changeable at the moment.